# Best way to import user profile on Mac from external HDD after data recovery on Windows?

Tags: macos, mojave, external-disk, user-account, import

For an iMac that had a crashed fusion drive due to damages in fusion data structures, **I had to perform a data recovery on Windows**.

From the data recovery software, **the user profile **(let's call it "john_smith")** was copied to external drive**, formatted in ExFAT.

The iMac was reinstalled with same user name ("john_smith").

**I'm looking for the best way to easily import everything**: documents, pictures, music, emails (if any), a.s.o.
I am very frustated by what the Finder (and other apps) let me do.

**Images**
On the external drive the "Images" folder has two libraries, one for Photos, and an older one for iPhoto. When importing from the Photo App, I'm not sure the ones from iPhoto library are also imported. And some files, like PDF documents (wrongly stored there) cannot be imported.

If double-clicking the older "iPhoto" library, there is an error message tells that it is impossible to open the migrated phototheque.

**Music**
Same nightmare with Music: How do I import the "iTunes" folder? I cannot see an import option in iTunes.

There are also "GarageBand" and "Audio Music Apps" folders.

**Other files and settings**

I am also not sure if a mail box was configured on the iMac.

Is there an easy way to restore everything from the profile, or at leat everyhing important?
I could find no option for that in the migration assistant.

Should I start the iMac in recovery mode and overwrite the user folder though terminal commands like `dd` or `mv`?

Comment: Why not just exporting a backup?

Comment: What OS *was* on the Mac & what is on it now? You have several levels of difficulty to overcome, initially some dependant on OS, others caused by having put the data on an ExFAT drive, which will have lost all unix permissions, ACLS, aliases etc and also library structures like Photos, Garageband projects,  so what you're left with is 'flat' data.

Comment: If you still have access to the original drive, it might be better to start the recovery again on the Mac, maybe using Disk Drill or similar, recovering to an HFS [or APFS, OS-depending] drive rather than FAT.

Comment: @Thinkr: The iMac was corrupt. Not booting. Unreparable damages in the fusion data structures. I tried many things (during days) to recover it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I am aware that exFAT is not journaled and means loosing metadata. However is was the only filesystem format to make the drive compatible with Windows and Mac. I have APFS driver for Windows, but the conversion makes it in practice excessively slow. I still have clones of the two original drives. Those fusion drives were logically reassembled into a fusion drive, using a DR software, on Windows. It is NOT POSSIBLE to start the recovery again on the Mac: the fusion drive was logically broken and all repair tentatives failed. New fusion drive was created and Mas OS Mojave reinstalled.

Comment: To punctuate what @Tetsujin said, you’re out of options for a clean import - this is where a Time Machine backup would be your salvation.  What you have from your Windows recovery is just data - there’s no structure, no permissions, and it’s not even certain at this point whether the data is valid.  Your best bet is to categorize your data somehow (Documents, Photos, Music, etc.) and manually recreate your libraries.

Comment: The libraries are still there, in the Image folder and the photos could be imported. Documents, Desktop, Download folders still have the files and folders that I could copy-paste in the user account. I still have access to the whole structure, from root (and could copy it again to APFS instead of exFAT), but it is not worth in this case.